# In fase di scrittura / viene scritto

Tags: passive

Quale frase va bene?

> Il testo si è ancora scrivendo.

> Il testo è in fase di scrittura.

> Il testo ancora viene scritto.

> Il testo sta ancora venendo scritto.

Comment: La seconda è sicuramente la frase più comune e comprensibile. La prima è sgrammaticata e le altre poco chiare.

Answer (score 1):

Anche io direi che la seconda è la migliore però aggiungerei che anche la quarta è comprensibile e grammaticamente corretta anche se è una struttura poco usata dagli italiani